# Javascript: Fetch list of usernames to console/file

Tags: javascript, html

how can I use javascript to fetch a list of the content of all the username class to the console or preferably a file?

```css
.user-id, .username, .user-year { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div id="#main">
  <div class="user-id">5</div>
  <div class="username">@user1</div>
  <div class="user-year">2018</div>
  <br>
  <div class="user-id">6</div>
  <div class="username">@user2</div>
  <div class="user-year">2015</div>
  <br>
  <div class="user-id">5</div>
  <div class="username">@user3</div>
  <div class="user-year">2012</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just select them using `querySelectorAll('.username')`, then `.map` `textContent`:

```js
let users = [...document.querySelectorAll('.username')].map(i => i.textContent)

console.log(users)
```

```css
.user-id, .username, .user-year { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div id="#main">
  <div class="user-id">5</div>
  <div class="username">@user1</div>
  <div class="user-year">2018</div>
  <br>
  <div class="user-id">6</div>
  <div class="username">@user2</div>
  <div class="user-year">2015</div>
  <br>
  <div class="user-id">5</div>
  <div class="username">@user3</div>
  <div class="user-year">2012</div>
</div>
```

Comment: typo here `querySeelctorAll('.username'),`

Comment: Thank you! So what if I want to further sort the result, not all the usernames starts with an @, I have tried this:
`var users = [...document.querySelectorAll('.userRowTableItem')].map(i => i.textContent)
var matches = users.match(/@\w+/g)
console.log(matches)`
But do get an 
`VM1354:2 Uncaught TypeError: users.match is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:21`

Comment: Sure! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365829/javascript-sort-array-of-twitter-usernames-to-console

Answer (score 2):

You can use javscript and following code

`var users= document.getElementsByClassName('username');`

```js
var users= document.getElementsByClassName('username');

for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
console.log(users[i].innerText)
}
```

```css
.user-id, .username, .user-year { display: inline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="#main">
  <div class="user-id">5</div>
  <div class="username">@user1</div>
  <div class="user-year">2018</div>
  <br>
  <div class="user-id">6</div>
  <div class="username">@user2</div>
  <div class="user-year">2015</div>
  <br>
  <div class="user-id">5</div>
  <div class="username">@user3</div>
  <div class="user-year">2012</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is not tagged [tag:jquery]. OP explicitly asked for a Javascript solution.

Comment: Yes I got it But i have mentioned that you can do like this in Jquery if he wants to

Comment: He could also do this using, underscore, ember, angular, knockout and 100 other js libraries, doesn't mean answers using any of these technologies would be a valid answer. Please only add jquery answers to questions that include the jquery tag