# Javascript: sort array of twitter usernames to console

Tags: javascript

Ref. [Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365446/javascript-fetch-list-of-usernames-to-console-file)

I want to further sort the result, not all the usernames starts with an @, I have tried this:

```
var users = [...document.querySelectorAll('.userRowTableItem')].map(i => i.textContent) 
var matches = users.match(/@\w+/g) 
console.log(matches)
```

But do get an `VM1354:2 Uncaught TypeError: users.match is not a function at <anonymous>:2:21`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`users` is an array. Try [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var matches = users.filter(v => v.match(/@\w+/g))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Fjott - Glad to help you!